# Ordering of classes in doxegen rtf document

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to generate an rtf document of my C++ code.  Currently, the classes appear in the document in alphabetical order.  I'd rather order some of classes by inheritance (have base classes appear above derived classes).  Rather than manually moving paragraphs around, is there a way to specify the order the classes appear in the rtf document?